# Errors When Starting Icenium Device Simulator

Tags: html, mobile, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, icenium

I'm creating a new mobile project using Icenium. When I start the device simulator, I get the following errors:

Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined    about:blank:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined    kendo.mobile.min.js:17

Why do I get these errors?

Here is the markup from my header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<!--Style sheets.-->
<link href="styles/kendo/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--Scripts.-->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/kendo/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/kendo/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: We would probably need to see what is inside of your app.js file - there may be a problem with how you are initializing your Kendo UI Mobile app...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly the problem, Halcyon is trying to load a skin while the Application is still initializing. To fix this, one should pass the skin as Application configuration option on init, like this:

app.application = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, { skin: "flat" });